# Does LibSVM use Platt Scaling?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I have a binary SVM. I am wondering whether the percentage results that LibSVM gives for each class are Platt scaled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, libSVM uses Platt Scaling in its output. Although from the [source code](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/), it appears that libSVM authors implemented a modified version of Platt's method in which the maximum likelihood function is solved with an improved algorithm.